# Cannot remove the Kwikset deadbolt

Tags: deadbolt

I took off the two screws on the interior plates, but I cannot remove the plates. It seems they are glued to the door.

It is supposed to be an easy job, Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Possibly obvious, but do make sure the tongue is retracted.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like maybe there is just a bit of paint holding the cover on. Use a utility knife to carefully cut around the perimeter and then see if you can get a flathead under(insert at the bottom to hide the potential damage). You can also lightly tap with a mallet or a block of wood and hammer and it will probably come free